Pressure dependence on temperature
I was doing a problem on airflow around a wing, and how water will condensate on a point on the back of the wing. After reading the solution, it said that "The relative change of the pressure of the saturated vapour is small, so we can linearize its temperature dependence."
Isn't by the Ideal Gas Law the pressure proportional to temperature (or is the fact that there are phase transitions make it not applicable)? Can anyone expand more on this concept?
I saw something about the Clausius-Clapeyron equation and the Antoine equation when I looked online, but I'm not sure if they are relevant (if they are, feel free to enlighten me :)).
Edit: the problem I was doing was IPHO 2012: Question 1, Part B, III.
